# Programatic Use Of Properties In Apache Camel

Tags: properties, apache-camel

I am starting a project using Apache Camel and would like to add a way to store some information as properties. Most example seem to use Spring and XML, but I'm going the Java DSL way and can't seem to find good examples on how to do this properly.

I created a project from the camel-archetype-java archetype, and have only added Quartz and one route to it so far:

```
package com.commserv.integration;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class FilemakerCsvToMailroom extends RouteBuilder {

  public void configure() {

    from("file:/Volumes/Data-1/Camel?autoCreate=false&startingDirectoryMustExist=true&noop=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+*+*+*+*+?&scheduler.triggerId=EveryMinute&scheduler.triggerGroup=FilemakerCsvToMailroom") // every minute
      .routeId("FilemakerCsvToMailroom")
      .log("FilemakerCsvToMailroom triggered");

  }

}
```

Project code can be viewed at [this link](https://stash.commercialservices.com/projects/INT).

- Where do I add my property file(s) to this type of project? (I added it to src/main/resources reflexively, since the archetype has a similar log4j file there.)
- How do I make it usable in the above route in my project without using XML? Do I use the [Property Component](http://camel.apache.org/properties.html)? The problem with the doc at that link is that the short example all refer to `context` variable, but not sure where that comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the properties file to src/main/resources.

You can configure Properties Component with Java like this:

```
public void configure() {
    PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
    pc.setLocation("classpath:myprop.properties");
    getContext().addComponent("properties", pc);

    // Will output "result1" every 5 seconds.
    from("timer:mytimer?period=5s")
    .log("{{dev.endpoint}}");
}
```

if you have properties file src/main/resources/myprop.properties containing

```
dev.endpoint = result1
test.endpoint = result2
```

Note that you can call to getContext() inside RouteBuilder to get the running Camel context.

Comment: Do I have to add that code to every route configure()? Is there a way to load the properties at a "higher" level?

Comment: You don't have add it to every configure() and it doesn't have to be inside that method; anywhere where you can access Camel context is fine. Properties component is registered to the Camel context so you only need the configure it once. After that all routes in the same Camel context can use it.